# How can i make Dataframe for classification from movie review dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, svm, sentiment-analysis

I am new in pandas, trying to practice with some data. I get a training dataset in following format.
This is dataset for movie review. How can I make DataFrame from this kind of data to use in SVM classification. I already practiced with [12000*12] size data for classification, where each row has equal number of attributs. But here, attributes are not equal length. How can i modify this.

```
PhraseId    SentenceId  Phrase  Sentiment
1   1   Wanker Goths are on the loose ! 2
2   1   Wanker Goths    2
3   1   Wanker  2
4   1   Goths   2
5   1   are on the loose !  2
6   1   are on the loose    2
7   1   on the loose    2
8   1   the loose   2
9   2   made Eddie Murphy a movie star and the man has n't aged a day . 3
10  2   made Eddie Murphy a movie star and the man  3
11  2   Eddie Murphy a movie star and the man   2
12  2   a movie star and the man    2
13  2   a movie star and    2
14  2   has n't aged a day .    2
15  2   has n't aged a day  3
16  2   aged a day  2
```

This is actual training [dataset](http://www.codeshare.io/B5baY) (partial).

My target is to form a DataFrame from this Dataset with numeric data mapping so that i can use that dataframe to classify Sentiment.

Comment: i know pandas has a get_dummies() but i've never used it in a text classification problem

Answer (score 1):

With pure python:

```
t = """PhraseId    SentenceId  Phrase  Sentiment
1   1   Wanker Goths are on the loose ! 2
2   1   Wanker Goths    2
3   1   Wanker  2
4   1   Goths   2
5   1   are on the loose !  2"""
```

Splitting the string by the newline:

```
t = t.split('\n')
```

Then getting the list of splitted strings:

```
s = [i.split() for i in t]
```

And then merging the phrase and getting a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([(i[0],i[1],' '.join(i[2:-1]),i[-1]) for i in s],columns=s[0])
df = df.ix[1:]
print df
```

Comment: Sorry I only know how to convert this into a DataFrame.

Comment: Thank you, sir. I know this part. I actually need to convert further